# what are the other 2 pins for in this old dc motor (Sankyo BFB9L11)?

Tags: dc-motor, pinout

I received a box full of old electronic components and the pictured DC motor was in it (4 pins labelled as '+' '-' and 'P', 'P'). I would like to know what are the 'P' labelled pins for. Thanks in advance

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably "pulse" for a tachometer output (which may be used for a control input.)

Put a scope on it with the motor running.

Comment: Thanks @Ecnerwal, I've done it last night and it gave me outputs around: for white pin 0.8v, brown pin = 13v. If I force a slow down in the motor, white pin goes up and brown pin goes down. So it would be for a Tachometer output. It suggest you can control the speed by modifying input voltage according to the out of these pins